# HTML 5 Audio tag: play concatenated opus file in ogg container

Tags: html, audio, concatenation, ogg, opus

I have two sound files saved as opus in an ogg container. I've concatenated them using a simple technique: append the binary data of file B to file A. I can play the new file with my VLC media player, but the HTML audio tag just recognizes the first part (original file A) of the concatenated file.

Is there any way to overcome this problem without touching the whole binary data (e.g. removing old header and create one for the new file).

Regards,
Philipp